# Ошибка в IDE "cannot resolve a symbol"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdk11, java-11

Всем привет , писал код и вдруг IDE начала выдавать ошибку "cannot resolve a symbol". Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте навести на строку с import, там появится красная лампочка со списком. В списке должно быть решение вашей проблемы. Что то типа import javafx...

Answer (score 0):

Ты забыл вывести public static void main (String[] args){} за скобки метода start.
То есть, нельзя в одном методе создавать другой.
Чтобы было все верно и компилятор не ругался, ты должен сделать так:

```java
public void start(){

     ТУТ СОДЕРЖИТСЯ ТВОЙ КОД

}//Ты забыл закрыть эту скобку

И только потом отдельным методом

public static void main (String[] args){

  КОД МЕТОДА МАЙН

}
```